# Reputation report total slightly off from SO rep I see?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-page, reputation-display

My [reputation report](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) shows:

`** total rep 9434 :)`

Yet, on my SO banner, the rep shows as "DVK 9,432●5●33"

Which one is correct? Why?

The "2" difference makes this unlikely to be related to some timing/lag issue, since I only had a +10 vote and an accept all day today.

Please note that this is a technical question regarding logic in SO. Not an excuse to rant that reputation is irrelevant OR that it is the reason for existence :)

I'm guessing it may relate to double-counting (or not counting) my acceptance of some answer... but no idea how to check that theory.

Comment: It's a shame that the link gives the rep for the logged in user ;)

Comment: I see the same thing for my SO and MSO reputation reports, except that the reports show sums lower than the sums I see on the sites themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my status bar reputation different from stackoverflow.com/reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50978/why-is-my-status-bar-reputation-different-from-stackoverflow-com-reputation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reputation report shows your **future rep upon recalc**.

Probably, you've deleted a post with a downvote recently after last recalc (March 21st)

Or

One of your post with a downvote has been deleted by 10k+ users or mods after last recalc

(Note:Once a question is deleted, all the answers on that question also got deleted)

Or

2 of your downvoted posts (by you) got deleted as balpha mentioned

Comment: Hm... Don't recall doing that - is there a way to query this out somehow? And Yeah, I Should Instead Go Work :)

Comment: Interesting. If true, something explaining this should be in the FAQ (if it's not already).

Comment: Could someone please edit this answer (my rep's too low to do so) to make "future rep upon recalc" bold.

Comment: @DVK: It might also have been that two answers you have downvoted where deleted.

Comment: You're right balpha

Comment: I know it's not in this case, but it could also have been a revoked answer acceptance.

Comment: ChrisF, True, also a migrated question with a downvote. so many cases!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't--perhaps--accept an answer between opening the rep report and looking at the top of the page did you?

Comment: Not that I recall :)

Comment: See OP: "I only had a +10 vote and an accept all day today."