# Reputation calculation page and my reputation are showing different values

Tags: bug, reputation-page, reputation-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation report total slightly off from SO rep I see?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43805/reputation-report-total-slightly-off-from-so-rep-i-see)

Hi,

I am having an inconsistency between my current reputation and the reputation calculation page of mine. Is this how it is or this is a bug ?

https://stackoverflow.com/reputation link and my user link https://stackoverflow.com/users/252398/bragaadeesh are showing two different reputations.

http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/1583/repbug.png

Comment: Duplicate, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43805/reputation-report-total-slightly-off-from-so-rep-i-see