# Difference in reputation

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation report total slightly off from SO rep I see?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43805/reputation-report-total-slightly-off-from-so-rep-i-see)

On my user page I have reputation count `370` but when I checked my reputation calculation using the link `http://stackoverflow.com/reputation` it gives me `377`. Also the calculation gives me `377`, then why it is showing `370` on my user page?

Copy from reputation page:

```
** total rep 377 :)
```

Comment: Flag one of your posts, ask for a recalc, see what the number says on your profile.

Comment: I did a recalc; you got +7 as expected.