# Mismatch between reputation count at "/reputation" path and main site

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation report total slightly off from SO rep I see?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43805/reputation-report-total-slightly-off-from-so-rep-i-see)

Sorry to add to all of the posts on rep cap, but I noticed a slight mismatch (1 point) between my calculated reputation at www.stackoverflow.com/reputation, and the reputation that shows up on the main site. Specifically, at the "/reputation", I get

```
** total rep 2044 :)
```

while the main site shows 2043. Is this a known issue? I'll admit that I haven't gone through every entry in the "/reputation" table, and summed them all up, but I assume that value is correct (if only because it's the higher one!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The displayed reputation is usually slightly off if compared to the "real" reputation shown in the "reputation audit".

Votes on deleted questions/answers don't count to the "real" reputation, but the displayed reputation is not updated when a post is deleted.

In your case you probably downvoted a post (costing you one point) and that post later got deleted. In the "audit" report you got that point for the downvote back, but the displayed reputation was not updated.

Comment: You're exactly right. The exact situation you just mentioned happened not moments ago (probably for the second time). A post I downvoted was deleted, and now I see a mismatch of two points. Excellent deduction!